# Subtracting 10 minutes each from a vector of times in R?

Tags: r, open-source

I have a column of times like this:

```
"2:43::00 PM"
"2:43:01 PM"
"2:43:05 PM"
"2:43:06 PM"
"2:43:07 PM"
```

I want to go to each of the row and subtract 10 minutes from each of the time such that the new column looks like this:

```
"2:33::00 PM"
"2:33:01 PM"
"2:33:05 PM"
"2:33:06 PM"
"2:33:07 PM"
```

I am using

```
difftime(strptime(data$time[i],format="%H:%M:%S"),strptime("00:10:00",format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

, but it is not showing correct results.

How can i approach this problem?

Comment: Is the first one `::` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
format(strptime(str1, format = "%I:%M:%S %p") - 10*60, "%I:%M:%S %p")
#[1] "02:33:00 PM" "02:33:01 PM" "02:33:05 PM" "02:33:06 PM" "02:33:07 PM"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("2:43:00 PM", "2:43:01 PM", "2:43:05 PM", "2:43:06 PM", "2:43:07 PM")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.difftime` not `difftime` when trying to subtract time periods:

```
v <- as.POSIXct("2:43:01 PM", format="%I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC") - as.difftime(10, units="mins")
#[1] "2016-11-18 14:33:01 UTC"
```

Note that times in R are date/times by default, so the current day is just appended. You can `format()` the output back again if you want:

```
format(v, "%I:%M:%S %p")
#[1] "02:33:01 PM"
```